# Why do I get OperationalError: no such column

Tags: python, operationalerror

I have written below code:

```
def product_search_database (self):
    data=""
    data=self.ui.lineEdit_name_product_add.text()
    self.connection=sqlite3.connect("data.db")
    self.imlec=self.connection.cursor()
    self.imlec.execute("SELECT * FROM datas WHERE isim="+str(data))
    #row=result.fetchall()
    for row in self.imlec.fetchall():
        print(row)
```

and I get warning message:

```
self.imlec.execute("SELECT * FROM datas WHERE isim="+str(data))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column:
```

Where do I make a mistake?

Comment: Hi Yusuf. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Do you have column isim in table datas?

Comment: yes there is column as name isim in database

Answer (score 0):

`str(data)` - it's a string value. You have to wrap it in quotes, otherwise it will be interpreted as a column name:

```
self.imlec.execute("SELECT * FROM datas WHERE isim='"+str(data)+"'")
```